# Prevent user from pasting more than x characters in EditText but allowing them to type as many characters as they want

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

I know that limiting the text length of `EditText` can be done using the `maxLength` attribute in xml or using `InputFilter` using the below approaches

Using xml

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

Using `InputFilter`

```
myEditText.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(10))
```

But I want to enable user to type as many characters as they want while limiting the number of characters that can be pasted into the `EditText` using clipboard. How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Curious why you care where the characters are coming from? But one idea would be to set a text change listener on the EditText and check the changed text. If it's +/- 1 character, they typed, if it's more than that, they pasted.

Comment: @dominicoder Might want to double-check if inserting completions from a keyboard enters multiple characters at once; I'm not sure if it does.